# simulate cursor motion from X,Y to X,Y

Tags: python, python-2.7, autopy

I need to move mouse cursor from coordinates (800,300) to (100,600) with visible cursor movement.
How can I do that? (I need to simulate motion only - I am getting mouse position with [autopy](http://www.autopy.org/) module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the [docs](http://www.autopy.org/documentation/api-reference/mouse.html):

```
import autopy

autopy.mouse.move(800, 300)
autopy.mouse.smooth_move(100, 600)
```

This first moves to the location and then linearly slides the mouse to the second location. With a combination of pauses, you can use `autopy.mouse.move` to move as slow or as fast as you want.

**Edit by request:** To a finer control over the `smooth_move` you can set the mouse position yourself. Here, I set the total_time to be `5.00` seconds, but you can change this to be as quick as you like.

```
from __future__ import division
import autopy
import time

x0, y0 = 800, 300
xf, yf = 100, 600

total_time = 5.00  # in seconds
draw_steps = 1000  # total times to update cursor

dx = (xf-x0)/draw_steps
dy = (yf-y0)/draw_steps
dt = total_time/draw_steps

for n in xrange(draw_steps):
    x = int(x0+dx*n)
    y = int(y0+dy*n)
    autopy.mouse.move(x,y)
    time.sleep(dt)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know smooth move but it is too slow. Any other idea?

Comment: @peter Sure, like I mentioned, use a loop that uses `os.sleep` and `autopy.mouse.move` that moves it small increments. If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll try to code up an example when I'm by a computer (not phone) again.

Comment: Thanks @Hooked. I tried with sleep function but no luck. Could you please provide me with small example how to code it? Many thanks!